# How to set a container hostname when using --net:container

Tags: docker, docker-network

If you try to use `--hostname` with `--net:container` with docker you get an error:

> conflicting options: hostname and the network mode

So how can you explicitly set the hostname of the container when using `--net:container`?

Comment: You can't: you are saying, effectively, "from the perspective of the network, this container is the same as the target container". That means it inherits the interface configuration and the hostname from the other container.

Comment: You almost never need `docker run --hostname`, since it doesn't change anything visible from outside the container.  That having been said, trying to share another container's network is a little unusual too.  Can you explain more about why you need these specific options?

Comment: @larsks If you put that in an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @DavidMaze Passing one container to a VPN container. And I was using it before so I could easily do inter container communication -- making web API calls from one container to another container when both are running a web app.